# Can you compare a string with a user defined data type?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have a text file and a user defined data type arrays.

```
//for example the "hi" in the string a comes from a text file.

    String a="hi"

//user defined data type array
Box[] box= new Box[0];
box[0]="hi";
Box b=box[0];

if (a.equals(b){
return true;
 }
```

Is there any way to compare the "hi" in the text file with the other "hi" and return true?

Comment: `String#equals`? If you can't do that then you need to paste up some specifics. This is rather unclear at present.

Comment: Did you read about `String#contains` method?

Comment: Added codes as an example

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is possible if you add you have a data member in your class that return string type.

For example:

suppose you add in Box class the following:

```
public String text;
.
.
.
public String getText(){
  return text;
}

public void setText(String text){
  this.text = text; 
}



//user defined data type array
//HERE I CHANGED THE SIZE OF ARRAY ONE INDEX IN THE ARRAY [  ]
//conisder this is in main method
Box[] box= new Box[1];
box[0].setText("hi");
```

Now I set value in the array that hold "hi" at index 0.

Also I would to show how to get value and compare it with a string

in the main method suppose:

```
String myText = "Snowmap";

boolean check = myText.equals(box[0].getText());
```

If they equals then true will stored in check variable.